# 1) pictures in different/various styles 2) pictures of different/various styles

Tags: word-choice

How do you think, which variant is correct:
1) pictures ***in*** different/various styles
2) pictures ***of*** different/various styles

Comment: Either is correct but they mean different things. In 1, the pictures actually depict styles - a style is the subject of each picture. In 2, the pictures may depict any subject but are drawn/painted in different ways. When the preposition "of" is used with "picture", it denotes the subject of the picture rather than its medium or style. "This is a painting of a dog, in the Renaissance style."